# Redirect urls .htaccess, more than one link

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

So I have 15 diferent links that i want to redirect to other 15 diferent links

example

`example.com/example/example.html   -> example.com/example_new/example_new.html`
`example.com/example1/example1.html -> example.com/example1_new/example1_new.html`
`example.com/example2/example2.html -> example.com/example2_new/example2_new.html`
`example.com/example3/example3.html -> example.com/example3_new/example3_new.html`
`example.com/example4/example4.html -> example.com/example4_new/example4_new.html`
`example.com/example5/example5.html -> example.com/example5_new/example5_new.html`
`example.com/example6/example6.html -> example.com/example6_new/example6_new.html`
`...`

How to do this with .htaccess ?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive:

```
Redirect 301 /example/example.html /example_new/example_new.html
Redirect 301 /example1/example1.html /example1_new/example1_new.html
```

etc.